# Chat server-client in C. Using threads or processes?

Tags: c, multithreading, chat

First of all, the environment I'm working on is Windows 7 and [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

I already wrote a server that uses the select method to retrieve data from more than one client.

Also I wrote a client that connected to the server above, by running (`client.exe localhost 4444 Peter`). "Peter" is the username that this user wants to use.

Now let's say we have two users connected on the server. Each of them has the ability to run the command `/help`. This returns some other commands that the user can use. One command of these is `/listusr` that returns all the users on the server.

One other command is the `/talk2` and here is where my problem-question begins. I want to let the user choose to which of the other users want to talk. E.g if you want to talk to Peter, you give `/talk2 Peter`.

How am I going to start something like this? How will the server send the message from me to Peter (I have to add here that when a new user connects, the server saves his/her username and his/her socket number in a struct)?

Do I need to create new threads for each conversation or new processes? Can someone give me some hint or advice to continue my project? I'm little confused on how to manage at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Your server should maintain some kind of data structure that matches a user id to a client socket handle. When a request comes in with the `/talk2` command, the server should look up the corresponding socket handle for that userid and should simply relay that message using `send()`.

Comment: First of all i already made server to add each username with its socket into a data structure. Now lets talk on what you said about send(). I thought this solution too but it's little complex when i try to code it. For example here is a part of the code that sends to the client the results of /help command (http://pastebin.com/JztNCRYV). Lets say now that we have 2 users connected. and the one wants to talk to the other. The first one executes "/talk2 user2" and the server should now use in the send() function the socket of the user2 but the user2 must listen for any incoming message

Comment: ( so this means for me that i have to use the select method in the clients too). One other problem is that i must use a loop in the server that will stop only when this conversation stop. Also what if 3 or more users want to talk together? Hmm I'm so confused. I don't know which model to use for these client-server apps.

Comment: No, that's not what you should do. Let's say peter wants to talk to john. You should either 1.Assign Peter with John's username so whenever peter sends `talk2` command, it automatically assumes John's the recipient. or 2.Always send John's username with `talk2` command whenever Peter wants to say something to John. Method 2 is actually how IRC works. Whenever you say something, it also sends the recipient every time (channel, userid, etc)

Comment: So finally i decided to make it like the No 2 solution you gave. But my opinion is that the client still needs the select method for asynchronous messaging. So lets say Peter and John are connected. Whatever they write , server send it to all sockets that are connected (that's simple). The problem starts with the receive of that msg from the client. In my opinion must use the select method to search for incoming and outcoming messages. I cannot imagine a way to do this without select(). And when we have 3 or more clients and the peter want to talk to john , then he can use the /talk2 command.

Answer (score 1):

A scalable way would be your sever is just responsible to tell both clients the IP address of the other side, and then Peter and you establish the connection so you can talk.

If you really want to have the sever transfer the conversation, you need to consider the following to gain a better scalability:

- Use [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) instead of [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
- Use thread instead of process

Comment: udp for chat server...? i dunno about THAT... And who doesn't use router these days? it's going to be pain in the a** to guarantee the delivery of message if you use P2P for private conversations..

Comment: Agree with you, there is no perfect solution if the sever needs to do everything.

Comment: P2P won't be a good solution in the next 1-2 years - until IPv6 is widespread enough to assume that enough people have it.

Answer (score 0):

- Spawning a new process would be an ordeal for the server if the number of users interacting at a time are high. But on the other hand it will be simpler to code.
- Threads do provide scalability, but then you must be extra careful in your code not to do anything silly. (For example, sending wrong chats to the wrong guys.)
- Use select/poll techniques (I am not sure how they perform in the Windows environment, but it works cool with Linux.)
- UDP will reduce transmission time, but I am not too sure if it's a good idea. Since you said you already have a code, it would be great pain to switch to UDP.
- Just sending the address of required client is also a feasible idea. It reduces a lot of effort from the server, but now you will require dedicated clients.

Try each of them and check which one works best for you. It's a design problem, so there can't be a hard and fast solution. It will depend on the usage of your application. You may also want to use (may be you are already using) the sendto and recvfrom functions.